# Point an arrow at specific digits in a number formatted with siunitx

Tags: tikz-pgf, siunitx

I would like to point an arrow at specific digits in a variety of numbers in a variety of number formats in a variety of font sizes and it isn't an option to draw every arrow manually. I've pointed all the arrows at the first number for demonstration purposes, but I would like to be able to point at any digit in each number. Is there a way to position the arrow based on the place value? I generally compile using XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=19mm,vmargin=13mm,includeheadfoot,headheight=27.6pt,headsep=4mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz} \usepackage{tkz-euclide} \usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings,calc,positioning}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-separator = {,},output-decimal-marker = {.}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec} \newfontfamily\myfont{Cambria}
\setallmainfonts{Cambria}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{graphicx} \graphicspath{{Default/}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont]
\node[left] at (0,0) {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textcolor{Gray}{1.}}; \node[right] at (0,0) {\num{976867695082.87}}; \draw[ultra thick,->] (0.35,-1) -- (0.35,-0.35); 
\node[left] at (0,-2.1) {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textcolor{Gray}{2.}}; \node[right] at (0,-2.1) {\num{9772.9216}}; \draw[ultra thick,->] (0.35,-3.1) -- (0.35,-2.45); 
\node[left] at (0,-4.2) {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textcolor{Gray}{3.}}; \node[right] at (0,-4.2) {\num{115698983.3302}}; \draw[ultra thick,->] (0.35,-5.2) -- (0.35,-4.55); 
\node[left] at (0,-6.3) {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textcolor{Gray}{4.}}; \node[right] at (0,-6.3) {\num{61074171.8288}}; \draw[ultra thick,->] (0.35,-7.3) -- (0.35,-6.65); 
\node[left] at (0,-8.4) {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textcolor{Gray}{5.}}; \node[right] at (0,-8.4) {\num{81872.56}}; \draw[ultra thick,->] (0.35,-9.4) -- (0.35,-8.75); 
\node[left] at (0,-10.5) {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textcolor{Gray}{6.}}; \node[right] at (0,-10.5) {\num{118010166.2449}}; \draw[ultra thick,->] (0.35,-11.5) -- (0.35,-10.85); 
\node[left] at (0,-12.6) {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textcolor{Gray}{7.}}; \node[right] at (0,-12.6) {\num{1036600250.575}}; \draw[ultra thick,->] (0.35,-13.6) -- (0.35,-12.95); 
\sisetup{group-separator = {.},output-decimal-marker = {,}}
\node[left] at (0,-14.7) {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textcolor{Gray}{8.}}; \node[right] at (0,-14.7) {\num{271528084.6175}}; \draw[ultra thick,->] (0.35,-15.7) -- (0.35,-15.05); 
\node[left] at (0,-16.8) {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textcolor{Gray}{9.}}; \node[right] at (0,-16.8) {\num{3591829.37023}}; \draw[ultra thick,->] (0.35,-17.8) -- (0.35,-17.15); 
\node[left] at (0,-18.9) {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textcolor{Gray}{10.}}; \node[right] at (0,-18.9) {\num{4735855358.70}}; \draw[ultra thick,->] (0.35,-19.9) -- (0.35,-19.25); 
\node[left] at (8.5,0) {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textcolor{Gray}{11.}}; \node[right] at (8.5,0) {\num{6162795621.24653}}; \draw[ultra thick,->] (8.85,-1) -- (8.85,-0.35); 
\node[left] at (8.5,-2.1) {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textcolor{Gray}{12.}}; \node[right] at (8.5,-2.1) {\num{95475.63}}; \draw[ultra thick,->] (8.85,-3.1) -- (8.85,-2.45); 
\node[left] at (8.5,-4.2) {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textcolor{Gray}{13.}}; \node[right] at (8.5,-4.2) {\num{18964906.93874}}; \draw[ultra thick,->] (8.85,-5.2) -- (8.85,-4.55); 
\node[left] at (8.5,-6.3) {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textcolor{Gray}{14.}}; \node[right] at (8.5,-6.3) {\num{424743070.9}}; \draw[ultra thick,->] (8.85,-7.3) -- (8.85,-6.65); 
\node[left] at (8.5,-8.4) {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textcolor{Gray}{15.}}; \node[right] at (8.5,-8.4) {\num{6886.7}}; \draw[ultra thick,->] (8.85,-9.4) -- (8.85,-8.75); 
\sisetup{group-separator = {\,},output-decimal-marker = {,}}
\node[left] at (8.5,-10.5) {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textcolor{Gray}{16.}}; \node[right] at (8.5,-10.5) {\num{7038.187}}; \draw[ultra thick,->] (8.85,-11.5) -- (8.85,-10.85); 
\node[left] at (8.5,-12.6) {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textcolor{Gray}{17.}}; \node[right] at (8.5,-12.6) {\num{944938652566.421}}; \draw[ultra thick,->] (8.85,-13.6) -- (8.85,-12.95); 
\node[left] at (8.5,-14.7) {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textcolor{Gray}{18.}}; \node[right] at (8.5,-14.7) {\num{2927184.8}}; \draw[ultra thick,->] (8.85,-15.7) -- (8.85,-15.05); 
\node[left] at (8.5,-16.8) {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textcolor{Gray}{19.}}; \node[right] at (8.5,-16.8) {\num{8376.65}}; \draw[ultra thick,->] (8.85,-17.8) -- (8.85,-17.15); 
\node[left] at (8.5,-18.9) {\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \textcolor{Gray}{20.}}; \node[right] at (8.5,-18.9) {\num{235261584236.51}}; \draw[ultra thick,->] (8.85,-19.9) -- (8.85,-19.25); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image: Point arrows at digits]

Comment: If using a monospaced font was an option, this would be easier I think, but that is probably out of the question? (Completely unrelated: if you're interested in a slightly more concise way of making that, excluding arrows: https://gist.github.com/TorbjornT/42d57c860a91f60f1db3b2cb2c442e8d)

Comment: @freemath, just posted an answer, now I see the siunitx stuff, will think about it.

Comment: Well, it does not work with `siunitx` in its current form. Probably due to the expansion order. I searched a bit but I think we need a tex guru to solve this.

Comment: @TorbjørnT, would you have an idea on how to expand  a `\num{xxx}` to use it as an argument ?

Comment: @BambOo No, sorry.

Comment: @freemath, I posted another question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539570/how-to-expand-the-result-of-a-siunitx-macro-to-use-it-as-an-argument-for-another) it **might** draw more attention to your problem

Comment: I guess using siunitx isn't essential. I can build the number in other ways. I have figured out how to underline individual numbers using the soul package and building the number from scratch (e.g. digit by digit) rather than using siunitx; however, I'm not sure how I could go about using an arrow instead of an underline as I turn all the digits into a string.

Comment: @freemath, after discussing this on the previously mentioned topic, it seems it is not possible to manipulate the output of an `siunitx` call. So it seems what you ask is not feasible, at least not by me, sorry. Regarding this new topic with the soul package, you sould edit your question with the new code or post a new one.

Answer (score 3):

I am not overly sure this answers your exact problem, but here is my proposal using the `xstring` and `tikzmark` packages.

Basically what the `\addbelowarrow` does is

- Take a string `str` and a character position `index`
- Split `str` in three strings (`str(1:index-1)`, `str(index)`, `str(index+1:end)`, sorry for the matlab notation)
- Add a tikz mark to the character a position `index`
- Print the string character as if nothing had happened
- Draw a vertical arrow pointing towards the character at `index`

I believe there should much better alternatives but this is the only solution I could come up with.

Note that it should be compiled twice to work

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\addbelowarrow}[2]{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\charbefore}{#2-1}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\charafter}{#2+1}
    \StrMid{#1}{1}{\charbefore}%
    \tikzmarknode{tempnode}{\StrChar{#1}{#2}}%
    \StrMid{#1}{\charafter}{100}%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[stealth-] (tempnode) --++ (0,-2em);}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item  123456789
    \item  \addbelowarrow{123456789}{4}
    \item  \addbelowarrow{123456789}{4}
    \item  \addbelowarrow{123456789}{2}
    \item  \addbelowarrow{123456789}{7}
    \item  \addbelowarrow{123456.789}{7}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a too serious answer. Like BambOo's nice answer it uses `xtring`. However, it typesets the numbers with `siunitx`. One can reconstruct the horizontal position of the digits for a specific SI setting. This means that if you change your settings, the stuff below won't most likely work properly unless you change the pgf functions accordingly. You can say

```
 \path (0,0) node[name=test1,si node={76867695082.87}];
```

to create a node. The digit positions are then stored in coordinates `test1-digit1` and so on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\sisetup{group-separator = {,},output-decimal-marker = {.}}
\usepackage{xstring}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{punctuationcontribution}{2}{\begingroup
\pgfmathparse{(#2<5 ? 0 : int((#1-Mod(#2,3)+3*(Mod(#2,3)==2))/3)*2.7778)}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
\endgroup}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{simarkpos}{2}{\begingroup
\pgfmathsetmacro{\digitwidth}{width("\num{1}")}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\dotwidth}{width("\num{1.2}")-2*\digitwidth}%
\StrPosition{#1}{.}[\dotpos]%
\ifnum#2=\dotpos
 \pgfmathparse{punctuationcontribution(#2,\dotpos)+(#2-1)*5+2.7778/2}%
\else
 \ifnum#2<\dotpos
  \pgfmathparse{punctuationcontribution(#2,\dotpos)+(#2-1)*5+5/2}%
 \else
  \pgfmathparse{punctuationcontribution(\dotpos-1,\dotpos)+(#2-1)*5+2.7778+5/2}%
 \fi
\fi
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
\endgroup}
\tikzset{measure si node/.code={%
\StrLen{#1}[\mylen]%
\foreach \XX in {1,...,\mylen}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\mydist}{simarkpos("#1",\XX)}
\path ([xshift=\mydist pt]\tikzlastnode.south west) coordinate
(\tikzlastnode-digit \XX);
}},
si node/.style={inner sep=0pt,node contents={\num{#1}},
append after command={[measure si node={#1}]}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path (0,0) node[name=test1,si node={76867695082.87}];
 \foreach \X in {1,...,13}
 {\draw[thin,stealth-] (test1-digit \X) -- ++ (0,-0.25)
 node[below,font=\tiny\sffamily]{\X};}
 \path (4,0) node[name=test2,si node={976867695082.87}];
 \foreach \X in {1,...,14}
 {\draw[thin,stealth-] (test2-digit \X) -- ++ (0,-0.25)
 node[below,font=\tiny\sffamily]{\X};}
 \path (8,0) node[name=test3,si node={1976867695082.87}];
 \foreach \X in {1,...,15}
 {\draw[thin,stealth-] (test3-digit \X) -- ++ (0,-0.25)
 node[below,font=\tiny\sffamily]{\X};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]